# SQL Database vs Writing Java Serialized Objects To File?

Tags: java, sql, database, serialization

I have a web application written in java and it is about course scheduling. I used file system to store my data. I serialized my collentions (objects in them) and collect them into an serialalized object. Every user has a few file for system data and backup or prepared table data. My program is reading that file (only system data) when user entered and writing it to that file when user exit. 
Object design is very complex and there are many many-to-many relations between my objects. Writing data of this program requires so much join operation and well design schema in SQL. Furthermore a user generally have thousands of information containing hundreds of courses, teacher, rooms and even thousands of constraints. Beside of those, there is no connection between users. 
In this program I do not see any advantage of using sql. Even my system is running very fast. However lots of developers which do not know structure of my program advised to me to carry my database system to SQL.

What is the advantage of SQL against file system (with serialized objects) especially for my extraordinary system?

Comment: if you want more that a local monolitic app ..  a database system SQL or NoSQL can offer you ... maintenance, performance, scalability, language standard query, execution in distributed architectures, replication, maintenance, concurrent access, good management tools, portability, support a wide community, excellent features management storage operations data, ability to export and import data massively, indexing, referential integrity,  clusters etc etc ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name just a few advantages of using a SQL database in general:

- Scalability: You can move your data to a separate server(s) to reduce the load on your application server.
- Accessibility: Should you wish to release an extension of your program in the future, that program can run independently and still access the same data without you having to worry about locking files etc.
- Security: Database systems allow you to configure "privileges" as who is allowed to write data and who is allowed to read data.
- Portability: Should you decide in the future to upgrade your program to a different technology, the SQL language is an industry standard that can relatively easily be ported from one database vendor to another.  You can also port your main application independently of your database to another technology given both technologies has drivers / libraries / connection  / plug-ins / what-ever-you-want-to-call-it to communicate with your database.
- Backups: You can easily run a backup while your application is online. With a files, you might run into locking issues or alternatively have to shut down the application to do a backup.
- Human resources: You can employ a database administrator to take care of your databases and reduce the responsibility of your developers/engineers so that they can focus on other tasks.
- Monitoring: You can monitor or inspect your data, while your application is live.

However, usually application that uses a SQL database was designed with a relational data-structure in mind from the beginning. Without fully understanding your application, it sound like you have a very complex data structure and that it might not be that easy to migrate to a SQL database.  I would recommend that you also have a look at a [NoSQL database](https://www.mongodb.com/scale/advantages-of-nosql) which

- allows large volumes of structured, semi-structured, and unstructured data
- encourages object-oriented programming
- easy to use
- and is much more flexible than SQL

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory answer. Nowadays my biggest problem is time. My data structure is a little bit complex I think. Moreover users have tones of data and manipulating this  data with SQL will not be easy and creating such a thing seems very time consuming. However as you mentioned above sql has lots of advantages against data system. In the future I may need those advantages.